# Showing dynamic tooltips on multiple-choice Select control

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tooltip, angular-ui-bootstrap

Good morning:

I'm trying to add a custom tooltip to every selected choice in an `Angular JS ui-select` control ([Angular JS - ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)).

The controler (`fc`) contains a function which, based on the `contact`'s `fullName` attribute, obtains a `string` with the associated tooltip's text.

I can't seem to find how to have a different tooltip based on the choice the user is hovering on.

The control's code excerpt is the following:

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="fc.contacts" title="Contacts" on-select="fc.addContact($item)" on-remove="fc.removeContact($item)">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Add contact...">
        {{$item.fullName}}
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="contact in fc.contacts | filter:$select.search">
        {{contact.fullName}}
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

The tooltip we are trying to add is Angular UI Bootstrap's Tooltip control:

`uib-tooltip-html="fc.getTooltip($item.fullName)"`

The idea is that when hovering over `"Lorem Ipsum"` its associated tooltip will pop up, and when hovering over `"Foo Bar"`, its specific one will show.

[image: Select Image]

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this question is just about a year old but I was trying to do something similar not to long ago. Posting my solution in case anyone else is interested.

I pretty much had what you have in the snippet with the exception that I just wrapped the select match in a span tag with [Angular UI Bootstrap's tooltip attribute](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#tooltip).

```
<ui-select-match placeholder="Select person...">
    <span uib-tooltip="{{$item.fullname}}" tooltip-placement="bottom-right">{{$item.name}} &lt;{{$item.email}}&gt;</span>
</ui-select-match>
```

I put together a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rdrwoodall/3ats200v/) for reference. To be clear I used the same versions for ui-select and bootstrap as the Multiple Selection demo from the documentation to match styling.